# Google analytics does not show Event Label in real-time?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using the following code to send GA events:

```
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsHelper) getApplication()).getTracker(AnalyticsHelper.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
                t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                        .setCategory("XX")
                        .setAction("XX")
                        .setLabel("XX")
                        .build());
```

But on google analytics report webpage -> Real Time, it only shows the Category and Action. The Label is missing. Is Label ignored by real-time reporting? Do I need to wait for one day for the Label to show up?

Comment: If you select a Category, the real-time table will then display Action and Label. I'm not sure if there's a way to view labels without selecting a Category, however.

Comment: @stkent - this seems like a reasonable answer, it helped me to figure out where the label was...I would post this as an answer to this question and flesh it out with a bit of explanation maybe...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As @stkent answered, you have to click on the category to see the labels.

But also, make sure there are no extra filters added unintentionally

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know if it's possible to view the values of the events as well?

Comment: @pmb That's the value that you see. In the snapshot above the label category is orders and the label value is 247215

Comment: @Useless How about the value of the _value_ field, then?  As in the fourth piece of data that defines a hit of type _event_: <eventCategory, eventAction, eventLabel, eventValue>.   See also [analytics.js Event Tracking docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).

Comment: @UselessHasid Is there a way that I can see the event value field in this page? And how?

Comment: @ArjunNayak I think you misunderstand dimension and metric here.  The value is a metric and only the dimensions are shown in the real time API.  The metric is an integer value that is used to quantify your dimention

Comment: Any reason why the Event Label column doesn't show up when I click on the value that appears in Event Action column as shown in the image here https://i.imgur.com/YxDIOT3.png